# Adding a field that has more than one input

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an Access report built on a query, and the [TypeOfTest] field for every record is either "Alcohol" or "Drug". Is it possible without VBA to count the number that are "alcohol" and the number that are "Drug" and show it at the bottom of the report?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you use the Report Wizard and you get to the grouping level, put your `TypeOfTest` in a group above the others.  Then you can add a field the header or footer of the `TypeOfTest` group.  In that field, add `=Count(*)` and it will count every record in that group.